# Hibernate @ManyToOne and @OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, jpa

From my Entity ProductEntity I have a many to one relationship.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private CategoryEntity category;
```

**In myy CategoryEntity I have a OneToMany relationship.**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProductEntity> products;
```

I want to delete a product object and I use JPA for this.

**My delete method is basic :**

```
public void deleteProduct(String productKeyId) {
    ProductEntity product = productRepository.findById(productId);
    productRepository.delete(product);
}
```

For a reason I try to figure out, my delete is not working...

Comment: *my delete is not working...* In what sense is it 'not working'?

Comment: In the sense if i delete a single product i deleted all products from the same category of the product. Which is not really expected. In fact. Second option depending the cascade value i put, it didn't delete the entry i wanted to have deleted. In fact I found out the solution after publishing it. A very stupid thing to modify

Answer (score 0):

Simply this way :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<ProductEntity> products;
```